# How content in "XDG_CACHE_HOME=/cache" different from the content in "-d /build"?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

Below Dockerfile has environment variable `XDG_CACHE_HOME=/cache`

that allows command,

```
  pip install -r requirements_test.txt
```

to utilise local cache(as shown below) instead of downloading from network:

### [image]

---

But below `Dockerfile` also has `/build` folder.

So, I would like to understand,

if the purpose(content) of `/build` folder different from `/cache` folder

## Dockerfile

```
FROM useraccount/todobackend-base:latest

MAINTAINER Development team <devteam@abc.com>

RUN apt-get update && \
    # Development image should have access to source code and
    # be able to compile python package dependencies that installs from source distribution
    # python-dev has core development libraries required to build & compile python application from source
    apt-get install -qy python-dev libmysqlclient-dev

# Activate virtual environment and install wheel support
# Python wheels are application package artifacts
RUN . /appenv/bin/activate && \
    pip install wheel --upgrade

# PIP environment variables (NOTE: must be set after installing wheel)
# Configure docker image to output wheels to folder called /wheelhouse
# PIP cache location using XDG_CACHE_HOME to improve performance during test/build/release operation
ENV WHEELHOUSE=/wheelhouse PIP_WHEEL_DIR=/wheelhouse PIP_FIND_LINKS=/wheelhouse XDG_CACHE_HOME=/cache 

# OUTPUT: Build artifacts (wheels) are output here
# Read more - https://www.projectatomic.io/docs/docker-image-author-guidance/ 
VOLUME /wheelhouse

# OUTPUT: Build cache
VOLUME /build

# OUTPUT: Test reports are output here
VOLUME /reports

# Add test entrypoint script
COPY scripts/test.sh /usr/local/bin/test.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/test.sh

# Set defaults for entrypoint and command string
ENTRYPOINT ["test.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "test", "--noinput"]

# Add application source
COPY src /application
WORKDIR /application
```

---

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
test:  # Unit & integration testing
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes_from:
    - cache
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: todobackend.settings.test
    MYSQL_HOST: db
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    TEST_OUTPUT_DIR: /reports

builder: # Generate python artifacts
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../../target:/wheelhouse
  volumes_from:
    - cache
  entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"
  command: ["pip", "wheel", "--non-index", "-f /build", "."]

db:
  image: mysql:5.6
  hostname: db
  expose:
    - "3386"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

cache:  # volume container 
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /tmp/cache:/cache
    - /build
  entrypoint: "true"
```

---

Below volumes

```
  volumes:
    - /tmp/cache:/cache
    - /build
```

are created in volume container(`cache`)

---

entrypoint file `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Activate virtual environment
. /appenv/bin/activate

# Download requirements to build cache
pip download -d /build -r requirements_test.txt --no-input

# Install application test requirements
# -r allows the requirements to be mentioned in a txt file
# pip install -r requirements_test.txt
pip install --no-index -f /build -r requirements_test.txt

# Run test.sh arguments
exec $@
```

---

**Edit:**

`pip download -d /build -r requirements_test.txt --no-input`  storing below files in `/build` folder

[image]

`pip install -r requirements_test.txt` is picking dependencies from `/build` folder:

[image]

Above two commands are not using `/cache` folder

---

1)

So,

Why do we need `/cache` folder? `pip install` command is referring to `/build`

2)

In `test.sh` file.... From the aspect of using `/build` vs `/cache` content...

How

`pip install --no-index -f /build -r requirements_test.txt`

different from

`pip install -r requirements_test.txt` command ?

Answer (score 1):

1) They might be the same, but might not as well. As I understand about what's being done here is that, `/cache` uses your **host** cache (`/tmp/cache` is in the host) and then the container builds the cache (using the host cache) and stores it in `/build` which points to `/var/lib/docker/volumes/hjfhjksahfjksa` in your host.

So, they might be the same at some point, but not always.

2) This container needs the cache stored in `/build`, so you need to use the `-f` flag to let pip know where it's located.

Comment: What does --no-index signify in pip install

Comment: If I say, -f /cache instead of -f /build  would the result look same?

Comment: As per test sh, is /cache bring the send?

Comment: if you use `-f /cache` the result might not be the same, because `/cache` is your host's cache, not the cache built by the `cache` container (`/build`). `--no-index` : `Ignore package index (only looking at --find-links URLs instead).` It means that you are not going to `pypi` to find a package. In other words, if you use `-f`, you need to use `--no-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a couple of different formats for packages.  They're typically distributed as source code, which can run anywhere Python runs, but occasionally have C (or FORTRAN!) extensions that require an external compiler to build.  The current recommended format is a *wheel*, which can be specific to a particular OS and specific Python build options, but doesn't depend on anything at the OS level outside of Python.  The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org) goes into a lot more detail on this.

The `build` volume contains `.whl` files for your application; the `wheelhouse` volume contains `.whl` files for other Python packages; the `cache` volume contains `.tar.gz` or `.whl` files that get downloaded from PyPI.  The `cache` volume is only consulted when downloading things; the `build` and `wheelhouse` volumes are used to install code without needing to try to download at all.

The pip `--no-index` option says "don't contact public PyPI"; `-f /build` says "use artifacts located here".  The environment variables mentioning `/wheelhouse` also have an effect.  These combine to let you install packages using only what you've already built.

---

The Docker Compose setup is a pretty long-winded way to build your application as wheels, and then make it available to a runtime image that doesn't have a toolchain.

The `cache` container does literally nothing.  It has the two directories you show: `/cache` is a host-mounted directory, and `/build` is an anonymous volume.  Other containers have `volumes_from: cache` to reuse these volumes.  (Style-wise, [adding named `volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) to the `docker-compose.yml` is almost definitely better.)

The `builder` container only runs [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/).  It mounts an additional directory, `./target` from the point of view of the `Dockerfile`, on to `/wheelhouse`.  The [`pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#id40) documentation discusses how caching works: if it downloads files they go into `$XDG_CACHE_DIR` (the `/cache` volume directory), and if it builds wheels they go into the `/wheelhouse` volume directory.  The output of `pip wheel` will go into the `/build` volume directory.

The `test` container, at startup time, downloads some additional packages and puts them in the `build` volume.  Then it does `pip install --no-index` to install packages only using what's in the `build` and `wheelhouse` volumes, without calling out to PyPI at all.

---

This setup is pretty complicated for what it does.  Some general guidelines I'd suggest here:

- Prefer named volumes to data-volume containers.  (Very early versions of Docker didn't have named volumes, but anything running on a modern Linux distribution will.)
- Don't establish a virtual environment inside your image; just install directly into the system Python tree.
- Install software at image build time (in the Dockerfile), not at image startup time (in an entrypoint script).
- Don't declare `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile pretty much ever; it's not necessary for this setup and when it has effects it's usually more confusing than helpful.

A more typical setup would be to build all of this, in one shot, in a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  The one downside of this is that downloads aren't cached across builds: if your list of requirements doesn't change then Docker will reuse it as a set, but if you add or remove any single thing, Docker will repeat the `pip` command to download the whole set.

This would look roughly like (not really tested):

```sh
# First stage: build and download wheels
FROM python:3 AS build

# Bootstrap some Python dependencies.
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
 && pip install wheel

# This stage can need some extra host dependencies, like
# compilers and C libraries.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qy python-dev libmysqlclient-dev

# Create a directory to hold built wheels.
RUN mkdir /wheel

# Install the application's dependencies (only).
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir=/wheel -r requirements.txt \
 && pip install --no-index --find-links=/wheel -r requirements.txt

# Build a wheel out of the application.
COPY . .
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir=/wheel --no-index --find-links=/wheel .

# Second stage: actually run the application.
FROM python:3

# Bootstrap some Python dependencies.
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
 && pip install wheel

# Get the wheels from the first stage.
RUN mkdir /wheel
COPY --from=build /wheel /wheel

# Install them.
RUN pip install --no-index --find-links=/wheel /wheel/*.whl

# Standard application metadata.
# The application should be declared as entry_points in setup.py.
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["the_application"]
```

Comment: As you said: if it downloads files they go into $XDG_CACHE_DIR... Then why do we need "pip download -d /build", if the packages are getting downloaded in /cache amidst pip install?

Comment: If PyPI doesn’t have a prebuilt wheel, the cache directory will contain the source .tar.gz file, but you want the resulting wheel at installation time.

Comment: are you saying that requirements dependency source code will always go in /cache but the resulting .whl of each dependency will get stored in /built... Correct?

Comment: So... For unit and integration testing, you need dependency source code(available in /cache) But for build you need .whl package( available in /build) of that dependency... Is that what you are saying?

Comment: For unit testing, run `pytest` outside of Docker.  For integration testing, run the exact image you’re planning to run in production, and drive the tests from somewhere else.